# Pronunciation of “SUS” in “Stainless Steel SUS 304”

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations, technical

How do engineers and the like who are native speakers of English pronounce “SUS” (stainless steel)?

Like the verb “suss”?

Like “SOS” (mayday) but with “U”?

Comment: Are you even sure there is one main way that native English speakers who have heard of this pronounce it?  (Probably 99% or more have never heard of it, let alone tried to pronounce it.) Consider the database language SQL, for instance: even among those who speak of it many times a day, there are two camps: those who pronounce it as "ess cue ell" and those who pronounce it as "sequel".

Comment: @Drew: and then there are those of us who think both the "ess cue ell" and the "sequel" pronunciations are wrong, as it should really be pronounced "squeal". :)

Comment: I, and most people I know in the UK, would refer to stainless steel as a material as 'stainless' as a free-standing noun. For example "'It'd last longer if you made it out of stainless instead of aluminium." I've never heard of SUS being used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incredibly niche in terms of usage. One company might use it as an acronym while another will use it as an initialism. The term SUS (Steel Use Stainless) is only used in Japan Industrial Standard (JIS) and there are talks about it being phased out.

Acronym is when the initials are pronounced as a word. Some examples:

- NATO (Nay-Toe)
- NASA (Nah-Sah)
- GUI (Gooey)
- FIFA (Fee-Fa)
- IRRI (Eery)
- AWOL (Aye-Wall)

Initialism is when the initials are pronounced:

- CEO (See, Ee, Oh)
- IRS (Eye, Ar, Ess)
- TV (Tee, Vee)
- CIA (See, Eye, Aye)
- NSA (En, Ess, Aye)

To answer you question, though (with knowledge that this might be a unique occurrence and that it might differ from place to place), the most logical pronunciation (as an English native speaker) is:

> ***suss***.

This would be in favor as it is one syllable as oppose to three in the initialism use.

---

There are various other standards for steel grades.

The Society of Automotive Engineers ([SAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_steel_grades)) standard is the most accepted form of defining steel grade. SAE also maintains the [UNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_numbering_system) standardization. SAE is most common used globally, followed by the British Standards Institution ([BSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSI_Group)).

ISO ([ISO/TS 4949:2003](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=37676)) standard has been widely adopted as another form of defining stainless steel grades that do not use the US or British standards.

> ISO/TS 4949:2003 sets out rules for the designation of internationally standardized steel grades by means of symbolic letters and numbers to express application and principal characteristics (e.g. mechanical, physical, chemical) so as to provide an abbreviated identification of steel grades.

The AISI standardized system, which is pronounced "I-see", from the American Iron and Steel Institute, has also been deprecated and authority given to SAE.

Comment: _GUI_ is both initialism and acronym: it is varyingly pronounced [ˈɡuː.i], [ɡwiː], or [ˌʤiː ˌjuː ˈaɪ].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I usually hear it pronounced as gooey.

Answer (score 1):

"SUS," short for "steel use stainless," is not the English of native speakers in the first place.  That is, virtually no native speaker of English uses this term in an English context.  It must be considered Japanese English (和製英語), and thus it seems reasonable to rely on the pronunciation of native speakers of Japanese English: the Japanese.

Still, as unfamiliar initialisms seem more often to be spelled out, while frequently encountered ones may come to be treated as acronyms for the sake of efficiency, the pronunciation "suss" does suggest a high degree of familiarity with the term.

If you're editing a document, my concern is with the audience.  The term "SUS," however pronounced, risks failing to be understood outside of Japan no matter what language is being spoken.  It may be better to rephrase as "stainless steel" or at least include some explanation, depending on the audience.

I'm a native speaker of English and agree with the answerer who said that this is incredibly niche.  If I were you, and I were dead-set on keeping the term as is, I would advise the spelled out pronunciation S-U-S for a more general audience, and the pronunciation "suss" (サッス or similar) for more specialized audiences familiar with the term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker of English but I've worked for a company where we used different types of steel sheets. Speaking from experience, it is pronounced "es you es".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I am asking specifically about native speakers of English because among the people I am editing for, native speakers of Japanese, “SUS” seems to be often pronounced as the verb “suss”.